# Setting xdebug 3 Config Values In htaccess File

Tags: .htaccess, xdebug-3

I'm trying to set some xdebug 3 config values in an `.htaccess` file, but I keep getting "500 Internal Server Error" results.

With xdebug 2 I could set config values by using `php_flag` instructions, such as:

```
php_flag xdebug.remote_autostart on
```

With xdebug 3 the xdebug config settings have changed, but all but one setting is supposed to be available in `.htaccess` (`xdebug.mode` is the lone exception). According to [xdebug documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings):

> Unless specifically mentioneds, each setting can be set in php.ini, files like 99-xdebug.ini, but also in Apache's .htaccess and PHP-FPM's .user.ini files.

I also tried setting the `XDEBUG_CONFIG` environmental variable in `.htaccess` but PhpStorm is not honoring it (setting `XDEBUG_CONFIG` does not generate a "500" page).

```
SetEnv XDEBUG_CONFIG "start_with_request=yes client_host=localhost"
```

I could enable xdebug in my `php.ini` file, but I don't want it enabled for all the local php code I'm running. Enabling xdebug in an `.htaccess` file allows me to only enable it for specific projects or code.

I'm running PHP 8.0 via MAMP on macOS, and coding/debugging in PhpStorm 2021.3 using xdebug v3.0.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was "solved" by fixing the syntax error in my `php_flag` instructions. When I copied the working settings from the `php.ini` file I forgot to remove the `=` between the setting and the value.

```
# incorrect - caused the "500 Internal Server Error" results
php_flag xdebug.start_with_request=yes

# correct = without the "="
php_flag xdebug.start_with_request yes
```

Sorry for the false alarm.